# Using cookie but not geting the value in cookie

Tags: laravel-8

In laravel, login module entering email and password and from database i am getting the entire record; and using echo print_r($userDetail),getting entire value of record on that user but in cookie no value is stored. After logging navigated to dashboard page but there is no value in cookie. Why there is no value in cookie. Here is my code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaJgv.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0tEa.jpg)